# Is it possible to insert into a trie one character at at time?

Tags: c

Reading characters from a file using `fgetc` and checking `isalpha()`, can I then insert that character into the trie one character at a time until it reaches the end of the word aka when a non-alphabetical character is found?

Comment: This sounds like homework. If it is homework, please explain it is homework and *exactly* what you were asked to do and *exactly* where you are having trouble.

Comment: yes, this is homework. And yeah i meant isalpha(). The problem statement requires us to read a dictionary file which is filled which alphabet characters and irrelevant characters. So, I'm using isaplha() to screen for the alphabetic characters. But, I'm stuck on how to start inserting the characters one by one into the trie.

Comment: When you insert a complete word, you also have to loop over the characters and handle one at a time. So do the same thing.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
void readDict(FILE *dict_file)
{
    int curr;

    while ( (curr = fgetc(dict_file))!= EOF)
    {
        int i;
        char a[50];
        for (i=0;i<50;i++)
        {
            if(isalpha(curr))
            a[i]=curr;
            if(!isalpha(curr)&&a!=NULL)
            insert(root,a);
            a=NULL;
        }
    }
}
```